# How do I reconcile predictions from keras flow_from_dataframe to actual labels?

Tags: python, machine-learning, keras

I've been researching this issue and while there seems to be references to it, I wasn't able to to get it to work.

I'm using keras `flow_from_dataframe`. My file names and labels are stored in two dataframes, one for train (df) and one for validation (dfv).
As I train my model the validation accuracy is at .75. I can verify that looking at `model.history`. Even `model.evaluate_generator` will confirm the exact same values.
But when I do a `model.predict_generator` using the exact same validation dataset provided to `.fit` and `model.evaluate_generator`, I get essentially randomness (.5), which tells me that either something with the order of observation is going on, or that there might be parts of the pipeline that are not carried on to the evaluation part (like  rescaling).

Here's my code:

```
datagen=ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1./255.)

train_generator=datagen.flow_from_dataframe(
    dataframe=df,
    directory=path+'\\img.tar\\img',
    x_col="loc",
    y_col="target",
    weight_col=None,
    target_size=(32, 32),
    color_mode="rgb",
    classes=None,
    class_mode="binary",
    batch_size=100,
    shuffle=True,
    seed=SEED,
    save_to_dir=None,
    save_prefix="",
    save_format="png",
    subset=None,
    interpolation="nearest",
    validate_filenames=True
)
valid_generator=datagen.flow_from_dataframe(
    dataframe=dfv,
    directory=path+'\\img.tar\\img',
    x_col="loc",
    y_col="target",
    weight_col=None,
    target_size=(32, 32),
    color_mode="rgb",
    classes=None,
    class_mode="binary",
    batch_size=100,
    shuffle=False,
    seed=SEED,
    save_to_dir=None,
    save_prefix="",
    save_format="png",
    subset=None,
    interpolation="nearest",
    validate_filenames=True
)

#Found 8500 validated image filenames belonging to 2 classes.
#Found 500 validated image filenames belonging to 2 classes.

from keras.models import Sequential
#Import from keras_preprocessing not from keras.preprocessing
from keras_preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator
from keras.layers import Dense, Activation, Flatten, Dropout, BatchNormalization
from keras.layers import Conv2D, MaxPooling2D
from keras import regularizers, optimizers
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

model = Sequential()
model.add(Conv2D(32, (3, 3), padding='same',
                 input_shape=(32,32,3)))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(Conv2D(32, (3, 3)))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))
model.add(Dropout(0.25))
model.add(Conv2D(64, (3, 3), padding='same'))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(Conv2D(64, (3, 3)))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))
model.add(Dropout(0.25))
model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(512))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.5))
model.add(Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'))
model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer='adam',metrics=["accuracy"])

STEP_SIZE_TRAIN=train_generator.n//train_generator.batch_size
STEP_SIZE_VALID=valid_generator.n//valid_generator.batch_size
#STEP_SIZE_TEST=test_generator.n//test_generator.batch_size

hx = model.fit_generator(generator=train_generator,
                    steps_per_epoch=STEP_SIZE_TRAIN,
                    validation_data=valid_generator,
                    validation_steps=STEP_SIZE_VALID,
                    epochs=1
)

#Epoch 1/1
#85/85 [==============================] - 74s 871ms/step - loss: 0.6584 - accuracy: 0.6398 - val_loss: 0.6059 - val_accuracy: 0.7500

hx.history

#{'val_loss': [0.6059464812278748],
 #'val_accuracy': [0.75],
 #'loss': [0.6583675097016727],
 #'accuracy': [0.6397647]}

model.evaluate_generator(generator=valid_generator,
steps=STEP_SIZE_VALID)

#[0.6059464812278748, 0.75]

pred=model.predict_generator(valid_generator,verbose=1,steps=STEP_SIZE_VALID)

roc_auc_score(dfv.label.values,pred.ravel())
#0.51
print(roc_auc_score(dfv.label.values,pred.ravel()>df['label'].mean()))
print(roc_auc_score(dfv.label.values,pred.ravel()>0.5))
#0.5
#0.5
```

Comment: Could you try resetting the valid_generator before predict() ? with ` valid_generator.reset()`. You can also get the matching filenames with `valid_generator.filenames`

Comment: Tried that and get the same results. The filenames is what drives me nuts. If I do np.mean(valid_generator.filenames == dfv['loc']) this gets me 1.0, meaning the filenames are in the same orders as the dataframe. But If I do np.mean(valid_generator.labels == dfv['label']), I get 0.5, which is in line with the prediction issue, but doesn't align with filenames.

Comment: Ok. I found this [issue](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/issues/11841) and the associated commit is still in the current [code](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/blob/7a39b6c62d43c25472b2c2476bd2a8983ae4f682/keras/preprocessing/image.py#L420) : "If [shuffle] set to False, sorts the data in alphanumeric order.". Can you try sorting your dataframe in alphanumeric order too ? Also, can you try with `shuffle=None` ?